# Normalized NSString representation of NSURLRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am implementing an authentication scheme and need to normalize my outgoing http requests to an NSString so I can hash and sign them. What I am thinking about is some canonical form like this (Pseudocode from the AWS docs):

```
CanonicalRequest =
  HTTPRequestMethod + '\n' +
  CanonicalURI + '\n' +
  CanonicalQueryString + '\n' +
  CanonicalHeaders + '\n' +
  SignedHeaders + '\n' +
  HexEncode(Hash(RequestPayload))
```

I am using AFNetworking 2.6 for networking, so most of the operations are hidden in the AFHTTPRequestOperationManager. How would you guys approach this? Where would be the right place to plug this scheme into my AFNetworking manager?